# Counting the number of elements in a list ignoring adjacent duplicates

Tags: list, prolog, instantiation-error

```
count([], 0).

count([H,H1|T], N) :- (H == H1,
                  count([H1|T], N));

                  (N1 is N-1,
                  count([H1|T], N1)).
```

My intuition is that the first 'if' simply moves to the 'next head' and N is not decremented if the adjacent element is the same, however the second decrements if they're different. Then, when the list empties it is true.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding backtracking in Prolog slightly but shouldn't this produce the correct answer?

I get this error for example:

```
?- count([3,4,5,6],C).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] count([3,4|...],_972)
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Comment: Prolog's "or" is not, repeat **not** "otherwise".

Comment: So I should add a H != H1 clause to the second 'if' right?

Comment: the opposite to `==` is `\==`, I think, but do check [the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%3D%3D)/2).

Comment: `!=` is not a Prolog operator.

Answer (score 0):

`N1 is N-1` implies that `N` must be a number. but you call `count([3,4,5,6],C)` with the non-instantiated `C` in that position.

It becomes `N` and then `is` fails because it is still not instantiated.

Why do you subtract anyway? To count the occurrences, you should add 1 to the recursively found count, not subtract, when you detect such occurrence.

Or forget about `is` altogether, switch to constraints, and use `#=`. See [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more.

Comment: Okay I have updated my code slightly which has a new predicate to instantiate the counter. I'm now simply getting `false` for everything ? What do you make of it Will

Comment: completely new code, should be completely new question. :)

Comment: I have made a new question. Please let me know if I have made some error in posting it